# Directly Pinging a Device (IPV4)

Tags: ping, ipv4

Hello and thank you for taking time to read this.

So I have a device (FPGA with network attachment on it) that I can change the IP address on. Normally it is set to 192.168.xxx.xxx and I can change the IP and ping it without any issues. I can also directly connect an Ethernet cable from my laptop to this device, manually change my IP and subnet mask and then I can ping the device without issues.

However, whenever I change my IP to 131.xxx.xxx.xxx (anything that is not 192.168.xxx.xxx) and I likewise manually update my IP and subnet mask, I can no longer ping my device. Again, I have an Ethernet cable going from my laptop directly to this device. I am on my own 'private network.'

I realize that IPs in 192.168.xxx.xxx are private. Whenever I set my IP to 131.xxx.xxx.xxx, are there any special considerations that I need to take into account when setting up my network parameters? Here is a picture of what I am doing (I have my real IP blotted out, but I just set my laptop IP to be 1 higher than the IP that I want to ping.

[image]

Do you see any issues with my setup? Does my subnet mask look right (I assume [ip address]/16)? Are there any additional settings that I need to consider?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to change your machine's IP address to one not allowed for a private address range? 131.x.x.x is already owned by someone else, you can't just take it from them. This feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, the goal of changing my machines IP address is to help validate the network link. The 131.xxx.xxx.xxx is arbitrary. Are you saying it is impossible for me to change my machines IP because it is outside of the private address range?

Comment: "validate the network link" … how? Is that where this structure will eventually reside? How do you expect DNS to locate it, when the first place it's going to look is wherever that address range actually exists?

Comment: @CakeMaster: You have a serious misunderstanding of IP and netmask. Please study the subject before asking here, since learning materials are off-subject.

Comment: @harrymc, unless if you are suggesting 192.168.xxx.xxx is not a private IP address range and also unless if you are suggesting that 255.255.0.0 is an insufficient network mask for 192.168.xxx.xxx/16, please indicate which parts you have an issue with on my post. I am not an expert, but I believe that those are correct.

Comment: @Tetsujin, At my lab, we connect our 'device' to a local server. We set the IP to be 192.168.xx.xx. When we set it to a new address, we can plug it into the server and ping it. We are going to send one of these devices to another lab. They gave us an IP address (something 131.xxx.xx.xxx). They own it, their servers should be able to ping it. However, I would like to ping it in my lab to make sure that It works. I will also be reading/writing registers over the network link. The ping test is just the first test. Thank you again for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

> are there any special considerations that I need to take into account when setting up my network parameters?

No, there are no special considerations. As long as both machines share the same subnet, both hosts can 'see' each other and should be able to ping themselves. "Sharing the same subnet" means the first 16 bits of their IPv4 address are equal for a /16 subnet, or the first 24 for a /24, or pretty much anything length.

The local firewalls might be interfering though, so check their settings to make sure they allow the traffic you want.

However, you shouldn't use any public IP address unless you're authorized to use it. There are plenty free, private IP addresses and ranges with the RFC 1918 scopes 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12 and 10.0.0.0/8.

Violating that rule doesn't get you in prison but it will make it impossible to reach the same IP addresses on the Internet that you're using privately if you decide to provide Internet connectivity at any time. If you're *really* sure that you'll *never* connect to the Internet you can use any addresses you like.

Also, there are a few address ranges that you cannot use even in a disconnected private network, most importantly: 127.0.0.0/8 is reserved for the localhost loopback, 224.0.0.0/4 is reserved for multicast and can't be used as source address, and 240.0.0.0/4 is reserved "for future use" and likely can't be configured on many devices.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. It looks like a local firewall might be causing my issues. I will try to investigate and get back.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Zac67.  I have done this many many times "back in the day" using a simple crossover cable.